# How to read more than one input from command line using mpirun

Tags: c, mpi, command-line-arguments

I need to use MPI for a program, and take in a number from the command line for how many times a loop needs to be performed. I know that using mpi I need to use:

```
mpirun -np #numberOfProcesses a.out
```

but I don't know how to then add the command line argument to take an addition number adding something like this:

```
mpirun -np #numberOfProcesses a.out 4
```

doesn't result in the loop performing 4 times

Comment: Q: does your "a.out" have a `main(int argc; char *argv[])`?  Does it check for `argc > 1`, then read `int num_loops = atoi(argv[1])`?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I had the main() part but I didn't know about atoi :)